# Alignment of text in a text file generated by a pl/sql file executed in bash

Tags: email, columns, text-formatting, sql

I want to left-align text in a .txt file generated by a pl/sql query (.sql file) being called inside a shell script, and send the .txt file over an email using email command.

The issue is, the text file generated is aligned when I cat it but when sent over email it gets unaligned.

I tried using "column -t" command but that didn't work.

Comment: Please update question to include example input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If the file happens to be unaligned when you are emailing it, it may be due to the fact that generally most modern email programs use proportional typefaces, rather than the `monospace` ones that you will see on the terminal.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but on balance decided it would be less snarky to just clean up the question.  I feel your pain, though.

Comment: Oh, your option is definitely the less snarky one.